# Strange variable undefining?

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined, hoisting

Ok guys, so I have this code:

```
var q=(function(){
    var u,q,x;
    x=616;
    q=q_construct();
    qp_construct();
    return q;
    function q_construct(){
        var q,pro;
        q={
            a:1
        };
        return q;
    };
    function qp_construct(){
        console.log('1 ⇒    ',q,x);
        Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,'q',{get:function(){
            console.log('2 ⇒    ',q,x);
            var r={b:2};
            return r;
        }});
    };
})();
```

When I enter `y={z:616}; y.q;` into the console, I get:

```
1 ⇒  Object {a: 1} 616

y={z:616}; y.q;                 //  console entry point

2 ⇒  Object {a: 1} 616
Object {b: 2}
```

Yet if i change:

```
var r={b:2};
return r;
```

to

```
var q={b:2};
return q;
```

the result changes from:

```
2 ⇒  Object {a: 1} 616
```

to

```
2 ⇒  undefined 616
```

I can not find out why, when setting this variable name to `q`, the `q` from the inherent scope is redefined as `undefined`.  Something is niggling in the back of my head, saying I read something on "hoisting" that might help?

Comment: If you say `var q = ...`, then that means that the `q` in `console.log('2 ⇒    ',q,x);` now refers to the `var q`, which doesn't have a value yet.

Comment: Specifically refer to section 8. **Global+Local** in the accepted answer to that question.

Comment: Ok you say it's a dupe??? Say read Section 8, I'll take a look!

Comment: makes sense cheers...